# Excel VBA- if cell contains text copy paste to another row (uneven spacing)

Tags: vba, excel

im relatively New to VBA and ive been asked to come up with a Macro(or in the terms given to me Automate) to filter all the rows in my workbook that contain "Total" & "Average" over a month long period and adjust the positions of 2 cells to be in line with another row.Now i can normally Filter what i need filtered but the problem lies in how i need to format it Exported. i need it looking from this

e.g

```
 COL1       |   COL2   |    COL3   |  COL4
Report Date:| xx/xx/xx |   (BLANK) | (BLANK)
-------------
Service Group:| Repayments |
-------------
Total    xx | xx    | xx
-----------
Average     |  xx   |    xx
```

To this.

```
   COL1     | COL2     |    COL3       | COL4  |
Report Date:| xx/xx/xx | Service Group:| Repayments 
--------
Total       |  xx      |   xx          |  xx
--------
Average     |  xx      |   xx          |  xx
```

the problem im having (besides being a completely new to VBA) is how to have it be "Automated" to which I had the idea of assigning a Macro to a Button which when pressed would cut Paste (then remove the blank space)every instance of  (Service Group:) & (Repayments) up 1 row and over 3 columns
 so for another Example: after the filter the rows would be Numbered variously so Starting on Position: B6 & C6 MOVE  Up one and Over three to Position E5 & F5

Sorry for the Long winded convoluted explanation I tried to TLDR but i couldnt think of a way to better describe it. edit 1. Also the data is nonsequential

Comment: Your logic is off to a good start.  What I would encourage you do, since you state you're new to VBA is: Enable the Developer Tab under Options -> Customize Ribbon and check Developer.  From there, your Record Macro button will be available, next to "Ready" in the bottom left hand corner.  Press that, and do what you want it to do.  What this will do is record your actions and place them into VBA so you can read and understand them. Then hit Alt + F11, or under Developer Tab go to Visual Basic, which takes you to the editor to see the code. Do you have any code already you can share?

Comment: ill give what i have but it was just to test if my thought process was sound



Sub TESTTEST()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("B6:C6")
For Each cel In SrchRng

    If cel.Value <> "" Then
        cel.Offset(-1, 3).Value = cel.Value
    End If
Next cel

End Sub

im lookin mainly for is it an IF then statement to then trigger it to Find what i need and move it where its needed